# accessing nested dictionaries when you know the nested key?

Tags: python, dictionary

This one is probably pretty easy, but I can't figure it out! Suppose I have a dictionary with a nested dictionary, that I know the nested dictionary key that I can store in a variable, how would I access this value?

```
k = 'mynested'
nestedk = 'blah'


x = {}
x['mynested'] = {}
x['mynested']['blah'] = 1


print(x[k[nestedk]])
```

throws error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `x[k][nestedk]` -- the brackets are the same as when you write literal keys.

Comment: `print(x[k][nestedk])` the format is the same as the way you set it `dict_name[key1][key2]`

Comment: What you wrote was equivalent to `x['mynested'['blah']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight mistake in your last line `print(x[k[nestedk]])`. This line actually means that you are treating the `k` variable as a list which is actually a string and the characters of the string can only be accessed by an integer index and not by a string index.

Change the last line to the below

```
print(x[k][nestedk])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with x[k][nestedk]. You can access the values similar  to assigning values inside dictionary. As you are assigning
X[k] = {}
and  x[k][nestedk] = 1

The value is 1 and key for nested object is k so initially we get the inner dictionary by x[k] and then we get the value using nested key in your case nestedk.

Thus you have to correct your print statement like below

```
print(x[k][nestedk])
```